# Synchronizing datagridview and database table

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a datagridview and i have bind it to database.
But when I delete a record , or insert , or edit , the changes don't apply to my table
Is there any solution?
I want to use a little code and do it by wizard and visual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a event whenever a record is added, deleted or edited and have that event fire a fresh databind to the datagridview.

Comment: Yup,  since I asumme you already have some code the adds, edits or removes items from the database, you can simply inject your event on that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQLDataSource Control, and Bind the GridView with SqlDataSource Control. Take a look at the following url http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs